# Can't set margins to zero in a responsive menu

Tags: css, html

I tried to make a responsive header for my website, it's all ok, but i can not set the margins of the links to 0. You cand see in the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JNeN.jpg

What i want to achieve is to make all that grey background 100% width.

I followed this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYw-FE60Dws

I probably set some things wrong, i am sure, but i am a beginner.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png"></a>
            <a class="toggle">Meniu</a>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul class="active">
                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Acasă</a></li>
                <li><a href="despre.html">Despre</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicii.html">Servicii</a></li>
                <li><a href="proiecte.html">Proiecte</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
    /* responsive header*/

.toggle{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 26px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

@media (max-width: 940px){

    .toggle{
        display: block;
    }

    header .toggle{
        padding: 0 0;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    header ul li{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    header ul.active{
        display: block;
    }

    header ul li a{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    header nav{
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    header ul li{
        width: 100%;
    }

}

/*normal page*/
header a{
    color: #fcfcfc;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}


header li{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0px 20px;
}

header #branding{
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: 35px;
}  

header a{
color: #fcfcfc;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 16px;
padding-right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your question, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Where are you setting the margins for your nav links? Where are you setting it to zero? Its hard to tell what margin you are talking about in your screenshot. Maybe its the `line-height` you are thinking is `margin`? Please add more info to your question

Comment: @FaizalHussain What i want to achieve is to make all that grey background 100% width.

Comment: @TonyMoldovan That is the nav... not the nav links. Links are the anchor tags `<a>`. You said _"but i can not set the margins of the links "_

Comment: Right click the element > Inspect. You can check surrounding elements to find out what you are missing (you need to remove the padding from the UL)

Comment: @zgood I editet my CSS part of the post, that's the only thing i have that includes <a>

Comment: @TonyMoldovan This has nothing to do with margins I think, its probably not going full width because you have it in a Bootstrap `.container`.... are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @zgood No, I am not using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

there is a default padding for ul, you have to remove it when you don't need it. Just add 0px to the ul and you will have a 100% div
Try to use css box models to solve such cases
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xF0dhepbzD8

Comment: I modified it. This is it now: header ul{padding: 0px;}, but it's still the same. :(

Comment: FINALLY! I did  it. IT was something else in my code. Anyway, thank you very much!